# Using jQuery ready before jQuery is included

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are migrating a site from an old version of a CMS to new one. The core code is outside of our control, but we can add custom files/scripts/logic to the system.

We have a page which includes jQuery in the HEAD and then loads several bits of functionality using jQuery.ready()

In the new version of the CMS they have included their own jQuery, but in the footer. The problems are:

- we can't now include our own jQuery in the HEAD because it conflicts with their version
- removing our jQuery causes all the jQuery code after that to error out, because their jQuery loads in the footer so those functions are unrecognised
- we can't edit their code to introduce any scripts after jQuery in the footer

The question is: how can overcome this without being able to edit the core code i.e. the footer?

Comment: search about JQuery.noConflict : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Why don't you wrap you code in window load event? But anyway something sounds fishy and you should be able to load your own javascript code **after** jQuery is loaded from footer. i guess, whatever CMS you are using, there is most probably inbuild way of doing it, otherwise it wooldn't make sense. And to make it clear, you shouldn't load more than one jQuery version per page

Comment: @A.Wolff I know, it's stupid that there isn't a way to include our own scripts at the end of the HTML. But, can you load more that one version of jQuery in a page? But "namespace" it to variable - is that what noconflict() is for, as suggested in another comment? Then all my custom code uses that variable, leaving the CMS to use jQuery() ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing, Put all your code in `init()` method. And let it be loaded in head.

At the `footer`, after loading the Jquery library, Call your `init()` method using `document.ready();`

```
function init(){
   alert("hi");
}
//Jquery file loaded hear.

$(document).ready(function() {
    init(); //call the init method once Jquery loaded.
});
```

Comment: We have no control over the footer though.

Comment: Do you have control, after loading of JQuery ?

Comment: No. We can't add any custom scripts - unless we change the core code.